# Single eigenvalue implies $A=\lambda I$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A^r=I$ for some $r>0$. Suppose that $A$ has only one eigenvalue $\lambda$. What to show that $A=\lambda I$.

What I have so far is $det(A-\lambda I)=0$. Is the statement $A-\lambda I=0$ true since the $\lambda$ is the only eigenvalue? If yes, how to prove that?

Comment: No, $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ has only $1$ as an eigenvalue, but it is not the identity matrix.

Comment: Hint: What is the Jordan form of $A$?

Comment: I see. This is a good counter example. Maybe this question can be solved by characteristic polynomial? I want to finish the proof without Jordan normal form.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ have the same characteristic polynomial, so the characteristic polynomial is not enough.

Comment: Yes. I know the Jordan normal form can solve this question easily. But I want to try something else. I am wondering if the min polynomial $\lambda-1|\lambda^r -1$ can help for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $A$ only has one eigenvalue $\lambda \in \def\C{\mathbf C}\C$, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\chi_A(X) = (X - \lambda)^n$. The minimal polynomial $\mu_A(X)$ of $A$ is, as $\mu_A \mid \chi_A$ by Cayley-Hamilton, of the form $\mu_A(X) = (X- \lambda)^k$ for some $1 \le k \le n$. On the otherhand, as $A^r - I = 0$, that is $p(A) = 0$ for $p(X) = X^r -1$, we have $\mu_A \mid p$. As $X^r - 1$ does not have a double root (its $r$ roots are the $r$th roots of unity), this implies that $(X - \lambda)^k \mid X^r -1$ can only hold for $k=1$. Hence $\mu_A(X) = X - \lambda$, therefore, as $\mu_A(A) = 0$ we have 
$$ 0 = \mu_A(A) = A - \lambda I \iff A = \lambda I. $$

Comment: Yes! This what I was thinking about! Thanks so much for helps!

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is a matrix zero of the polynomial $p(\lambda)=\lambda^{r}-1$. If $\rho=e^{2\pi i/r}$, then the roots of $p$ are
$$
                          1,\rho,\rho^{2},\cdots,\rho^{r-1}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
          (A-I)(A-\rho I)(A-\rho^{2}I)(\cdots)(A-\rho^{r-1}I)=0.
$$
If there's only one eigenvalue, then it must be one of the roots of $p$, and all of the other factors $(A-\rho^{k}I)$ are invertible. After multiplying by by inverses of these invertible factors, you are left with
$$
                       A-\rho^{n}I=0.
$$